# SQL query for group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

SQL table in the below data format

```
Datetime           Type    Id  
6/18/2018 8:00:00   A      1  
6/18/2018 9:00:00   A      2  
6/18/2018 10:00:00  A      3  
6/18/2018 11:00:00  B      4
6/18/2018 12:30:00  B      5  
6/18/2018 13:15:00  A      6  
6/18/2018 14:00:00  A      7
```

Result table needed

```
Type Startdate          Enddate            Count Changeovertime

A    6/18/2018 8:00:00  6/18/2018 10:00:00   3   NA  
B    6/18/2018 11:00:00  6/18/2018 12:30:00  2   1:00:00       
A    6/18/2018 13:15:00  6/18/2018 14:00:00  2   0:45:00
```

Can you help me to get the query for the result?

I am using sql server 2008 express edition.

Regards
Dilipan.

Comment: Please apply some formatting to your posts next time.

Comment: What was the query you wrote? Please include it in your post, and don't forget to ask question. SO is a Q&A website after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use difference of `row_number()` :

```
select Type, min(datetime) as startdate, max(datetime) as enddate, count(*) as count
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by type order by id) seq
      from table
     ) t
group by Type, (Id-Seq);
```